# How to set timeout when using suds.js library

Tags: titanium

I am working on SOAP webservices calling in titanium. I simply want to set timeout for requests so if data does not come within defined time I can show proper message. Right now  I am showing loading message because of no timeout it is showing loading until data comes.

Here is code :

```
var soap_client = new soap({
endpoint : Alloy.Globals.url,
targetNamespace : 'xyz'
});
```

//Call web service

```
Alloy.Globals.callWebService = function(soap_action, post_data, callback) {

if (Titanium.Network.online) {

    Alloy.Globals.showIndicator();

    soap_client.invoke(soap_action, post_data, function(xmlDoc) {
        if (xmlDoc) {
            var xml = new XMLTools(xmlDoc);
            callback(xml);
        } else {
            Alloy.Globals.hideIndicator();
            Alloy.Globals.showAlert("No data found!");
        }
    });
} else {
    Alloy.Globals.showAlert("No internet connection!");
}
};
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Passing timeout parameter to soap constructor should solve a problem:

```
var soap_client = new soap({
    endpoint : Alloy.Globals.url,
    targetNamespace : 'xyz',
    timeout: 1000
});
```

You can check full list of possible parameters and their default value in [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/kwhinnery/Suds/blob/master/suds.js#L74-L86):

```
// Client Configuration
var config = extend({
    endpoint:'http://localhost',
    targetNamespace: 'http://localhost',
    envelopeBegin: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:ns0="PLACEHOLDER" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">',
    headerBegin: '<soap:Header>',
    headerNode:'head',
    headerEnd: '</soap:Header>',
    bodyBegin:'<soap:Body>',
    envelopeEnd: '</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',
    timeout: 5000, 
    responseType: 'object'
},_options);
```

In this module soap client is build on top of XMLHttpRequest, so you can try creating [ontimeout callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#ontimeout).

```
xhr = soap_client.getXHR();
xhr.ontimeout = function() {
    console.log('Timeout');
}
```

As a side note, using XMLHttpRequest object for making Http requests from Titanium app is quite unusual and I would suggest looking for module build on top of [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) / creating your own / forking current module and replacing XMLHttpRequest with Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.

Comment: +1 for possible supported parameters. However I have tried this but don't think it is working. It does not have any effect of timeout. Can you tell how to catch timeout exception here as I do not have any try catch only if else in my code.

Comment: @RoshanJha I've edited my answer with my thoughts how to get timeout callback + small sidenote about weird usage of XMLHttpRequest instead of HTTPClient from Titanium SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use external setTimeout method but you should edit soap library and set timeout property in that library code.

Comment: Can you show me how? I tried with passing timeout property along with endpoint and targetNamespace but don't know whether this property even exist